# How to use sed to replace every match according to each match?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, replace, sed

```
$ echo 'a,b,c,d=1' | sed '__MAGIC_HERE__'
a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1
$ echo 'a,b,c,d=2' | sed '__MAGIC_HERE__'
a=2,b=2,c=2,d=2
```

Dose sed can cast this spell ?

**EDIT**

I have to use sed twice to achieve this

```
s='a,b,c,d=2'
v=`echo $s | sed -rn 's/.*([0-9]+)/\1/p'`
echo $s | sed "s/=.*//" | sed -rn "s/([a-z])/\1=$v/gp"
```

OR

```
s='a,b,c,d=2'
echo $s | sed -rn 's/.*([0-9]+)/\1/p' | { read v;echo $s | sed "s/=.*//" | sed -rn "s/([a-z])/\1=$v/gp"; }
```

**EDIT**

The real use case is [here](https://github.com/wenerme/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc.d/rc_exports.sh#L63) and there is multiline content, Thanks to @hek2mgl, the awk is way more easier.

**EDIT**

My usecase

```
export LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:ex=01;32'


exts="
tar|tgz|arj|taz|lzh|zip|z|Z|gz|bz2|deb|rpm|jar=01;31
jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|pbm|pgm|ppm|tga|xbm|xpm|tif|tiff|png=01;34
mov|fli|gl|dl|xcf|xwd|ogg|mp3|wav=01;35
flv|mkv|mp4|mpg|mpeg|avi=01;36
"

# SED Version

read -rd '' exts < <(
for i in $(echo $exts)
do
  echo $i | sed -rn 's/.*=(.*)/\1/p' | { read v; echo $i | sed "s/=.*//" | sed -rn "s/([^|]+)\|?/:\*.\1=$v/gp"; }
done | tr -d '\n'
)
export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS$exts"

# AWK Version
read -r -d '' exts < <( echo $exts | xargs -n1 | awk -F= '{gsub(/\|/,"="$2":*.")}$2' | tr "\n" ":" )
export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:*.$exts"

unset exts
```

**EDIT**

Finale sed version

```
read -r -d '' exts < <( echo $exts | xargs -n1 | sed -r 's/\|/\n/g;:a;s/\n(.*(=.*))/\2:*.\1/;ta' | sed "s/^/*./g" | tr "\n" ":" )
export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:$exts"
```

Comment: I hope you're not seriously going to use that mush of read/echo/xargs/sed/sed/tr in your code. Just use one small, simple awk script (and not the one you currently have in the middle of an unnecessary pipeline in your question either). You've already selected an answer to this question, if you'd like help post a followup that includes the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/,/\n/g;:a;s/\n(.*(=.*))/\2,\1/;ta' file
```

Convert the separators to newlines (a unique character not found in the file) and then replace each occurrence of the newline by the required string and the original separator.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk -F= '{gsub(/,/,"="$2",")}1'
```

`-F=` splits the input line by `=` which let's us access the number in field two `$2`. `gsub()` replaces all occurrences of `,` by `=$2,`. The `1` at the end is an `awk` idiom. It will simply print the, modified, line.

Comment: Should be `awk -F= '{gsub(/,/,"="$2",")}$2'`

Comment: @wener The `1` is by intention. It always evaluates to true. `$2` would work only as long as `$2` is not `0`

Answer (score 1):

Perl can...

```
echo 'a,b,c,d=1' | perl -ne 'chomp; my ($val) = m|=(\d+)|; s|\=.*||; print join(",", map {"$_=$val"} split/,/) . "\n";'
a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1
```

**Explained**

```
perl -ne                  # Loop over input and run command
chomp;                    # Remove trailing newline
my ($val) = m|=(\d+)|;    # Find numeric value after '='
s|\=.*||;                 # Remove everything starting with '='
split /,/                 # Split input on ',' => ( a, b, c, d )
map {"$_=$val" }          # Create strings ( "a=1", "b=1", ... ) from results of split
join(",",...)             # Join the results of previous map with ','
print .... "\n"           # Print it all out with a newline at the end.
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're not seriously going to use that mush of read/echo/xargs/sed/sed/tr in your code. Just use one small, simple awk script:

```
$ cat tst.sh
exts="
tar|tgz|arj|taz|lzh|zip|z|Z|gz|bz2|deb|rpm|jar=01;31
jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|pbm|pgm|ppm|tga|xbm|xpm|tif|tiff|png=01;34
mov|fli|gl|dl|xcf|xwd|ogg|mp3|wav=01;35
flv|mkv|mp4|mpg|mpeg|avi=01;36
"

exts=$( awk -F'=' '
    NF {
        gsub(/\||$/, "="$2":", $1)
        out = out $1
    }
    END {
        sub(":$", "", out)
        print out
    }
' <<<"$exts" )

echo "$exts"

$ ./tst.sh
tar=01;31:tgz=01;31:arj=01;31:taz=01;31:lzh=01;31:zip=01;31:z=01;31:Z=01;31:gz=01;31:bz2=01;31:deb=01;31:rpm=01;31:jar=01;31:jpg=01;34:jpeg=01;34:gif=01;34:bmp=01;34:pbm=01;34:pgm=01;34:ppm=01;34:tga=01;34:xbm=01;34:xpm=01;34:tif=01;34:tiff=01;34:png=01;34:mov=01;35:fli=01;35:gl=01;35:dl=01;35:xcf=01;35:xwd=01;35:ogg=01;35:mp3=01;35:wav=01;35:flv=01;36:mkv=01;36:mp4=01;36:mpg=01;36:mpeg=01;36:avi=01;36
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I do understand awk.Currently I just feel sed is more friendly to me.

Comment: With `sed -r 's/\|/\n/g;:a;s/\n(.*(=.*))/\2:*.\1/;ta'` You are using sed constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. sed is the best tool for simple substitutions on individual lines but any time you find yourself about to use constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) you should forget it and use awk instead. You'd be able to learn awk faster than you'd be be able to decode (and God forbid enhance if/when your requirements change) the aforementioned script.

Answer (score 0):

Perl, another Perl alternative...

**d=1:**

```
echo 'a,b,c,d=1' | perl -pe '($a)=/(\d+)$/; s/,/=$a,/g;'
a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1
```

**d=2:**

```
echo 'a,b,c,d=2' | perl -pe '($a)=/(\d+)$/; s/,/=$a,/g;'
a=2,b=2,c=2,d=2
```

**Explanations:**

```
perl -e                  # perl one-liner switch
perl -ne                 # puts an implicit loop for each line of input
perl -pe                 # as 'perl -ne', but adds an implicit print at the end of each iteration
($a)=/(\d+)$/;           # catch the number in d=1 or d=2, assign variable $a
s/,/=$a,/g;              # substitute each ',' with '=1,' if $a=1
```